# Testing Chi Routes w/Path Variables

Tags: rest, go, go-chi

I'm having trouble testing my go-chi routes, specifically the route with path variables. Running the server with `go run main.go` works fine and requests to the route with the path variable behaves as expected.

When I run my tests for the routes, I always get the HTTP error: `Unprocessable Entity`. After logging out what's happening with `articleID`, it seems like the `articleCtx` isn't getting access to the path variable. Not sure if this means I need to use `articleCtx` in the tests, but I've tried `ArticleCtx(http.HandlerFunc(GetArticleID))` and get the error:

`panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *chi.Context [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *chi.Context`

Running the server: `go run main.go`

Testing the server: `go test .`

My source:

```golang
// main.go

package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

type ctxKey struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Route("/articles", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Route("/{articleID}", func(r chi.Router) {
            r.Use(ArticleCtx)
            r.Get("/", GetArticleID) // GET /articles/123
        })
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", r)
}

// ArticleCtx gives the routes using it access to the requested article ID in the path
func ArticleCtx(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        articleParam := chi.URLParam(r, "articleID")
        articleID, err := strconv.Atoi(articleParam)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), ctxKey{"articleID"}, articleID)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

// GetArticleID returns the article ID that the client requested
func GetArticleID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    articleID, ok := ctx.Value(ctxKey{"articleID"}).(int)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity), http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("article ID:%d", articleID)))
}
```

```golang
// main_test.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestGetArticleID(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name           string
        rec            *httptest.ResponseRecorder
        req            *http.Request
        expectedBody   string
        expectedHeader string
    }{
        {
            name:         "OK_1",
            rec:          httptest.NewRecorder(),
            req:          httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/articles/1", nil),
            expectedBody: `article ID:1`,
        },
        {
            name:         "OK_100",
            rec:          httptest.NewRecorder(),
            req:          httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/articles/100", nil),
            expectedBody: `article ID:100`,
        },
        {
            name:         "BAD_REQUEST",
            rec:          httptest.NewRecorder(),
            req:          httptest.NewRequest("PUT", "/articles/bad", nil),
            expectedBody: fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest)),
        },
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        t.Run(test.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            ArticleCtx(http.HandlerFunc(GetArticleID)).ServeHTTP(test.rec, test.req)

            if test.expectedBody != test.rec.Body.String() {
                t.Errorf("Got: \t\t%s\n\tExpected: \t%s\n", test.rec.Body.String(), test.expectedBody)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Not sure how to continue with this. Any ideas? I was wondering if there was an answer in `net/http/httptest` about using `context` with tests but didn't see anything.

Also pretty new go Go (and the `context` package), so any code review / best practice comments are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The ability to get the variable is provided by the router, that's why `r` is passed to `chi.URLParam`, however in your tests you are not setting up the router at all and so the global instance of the router has no knowledge of "articleID" since you haven't registered any pattern with that key yet.

Answer (score 17):

Had a similar issue, although I was unit testing a handler directly. Basically, it seems like the url parameters are not auto added to the request context when using `httptest.NewRequest` forcing you to manually add them.

Something like the following worked for me.

```
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
r := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/{key}", nil)

rctx := chi.NewRouteContext()
rctx.URLParams.Add("key", "value")

r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), chi.RouteCtxKey, rctx))

handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    value := chi.URLParam(r, "key")
}
handler(w, r)
```

All credit to [soedar here](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/issues/76#issuecomment-370145140) =)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with named path variables. I was able to resolve it setting up router for my tests. A good sample is shown in go-chi tests.

[Go Chi Sample test with URL params](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/cca4135d8dddff765463feaf1118047a9e506b4a/middleware/get_head_test.go)

Answer (score 1):

Probably late to the party now :) But maybe somebody else would find it useful.

I had the same issue and wanted to keep my tests structured in a slice, so I ended up creating a "helper" function in order to add required chi context to the request:

```golang
func AddChiURLParams(r *http.Request, params map[string]string) *http.Request {
    ctx := chi.NewRouteContext()
    for k, v := range params {
        ctx.URLParams.Add(k, v)
    }

    return r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), chi.RouteCtxKey, ctx))
}
```

Again, as @Ullauri mentioned, all credit for the solution goes to [soedar](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/issues/76#issuecomment-370145140).

But with this function you will be able to nicely use it in the slice like so:

```
{
    name: "OK_100",
    rec:  httptest.NewRecorder(),
    req: AddChiURLParams(httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/articles/100", nil), map[string]string{
        "id": "100",
    }),
    expectedBody: `article ID:100`,
},
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you're instructing the usage of `ArticleCtx` after defining the path `/articles`, but in your test you're just using `ArticleCtx` directly.

Your test requests should not contain `/articles`, for example:

`httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/1", nil)`

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, however I don't like the accepted answer that manually inject `RouteContext`. When writing unit test, I want to try my best to make sure that the behavior of being tested code is as same as in real environment and of course in real life the `RouteContext` is not injected by us.
Actually if you take a look at the chi source code, you will notice that the `RouteContext` was injected by `Mux.ServerHTTP` (https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/mux.go#L87)
So, to let chi generate the `RouteContext` for you, you need to implement your test code in this way, so the unit test is testing the same code path that will be executed in real life:

```
func TestGetArticleID(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name           string
        reqPath        string
        expectedBody   string
    }{
        {
            name:         "OK_1",
            reqPath:      "/articles/1",
            expectedBody: `article ID:1`,
        },
        {
            name:         "OK_100",
            reqPath:      "/articles/100",
            expectedBody: `article ID:100`,
        },
        {
            name:         "BAD_REQUEST",
            reqPath:      "/articles/bad",
            expectedBody: fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest)),
        },
    }

    testServer := httptest.NewServer(BuildRouter())
    defer testServer.Close()

    for _, test := range tests {
        t.Run(test.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, testServer.URL+test.reqPath, nil)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }
            defer response.Body.Close()
            assert.Equal(t, test.expectedBody, string(respBody))
        })
    }
}
```

The function `BuildRouter()` is from main.go:

```
type ctxKey struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", BuildRouter())
}

// ArticleCtx gives the routes using it access to the requested article ID in the path
func ArticleCtx(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        articleParam := chi.URLParam(r, "articleID")
        articleID, err := strconv.Atoi(articleParam)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), ctxKey{"articleID"}, articleID)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

// GetArticleID returns the article ID that the client requested
func GetArticleID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    articleID, ok := ctx.Value(ctxKey{"articleID"}).(int)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity), http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("article ID:%d", articleID)))
}

func BuildRouter() chi.Router {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Route("/articles", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Route("/{articleID}", func(r chi.Router) {
            r.Use(ArticleCtx)
            r.Get("/", GetArticleID) // GET /articles/123
        })
    })

    return r
}
```