# How to pass path param to httptest request

Tags: unit-testing, http, go, path-parameter

I am writing the unit test case for my http APIs, i need to pass the path param to the API endpoint

```
GetProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    uuidString := chi.URLParam(r, "uuid")
    uuid1, err := uuid.FromString(uuidString)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        _, _ = w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
}
```

I need to test this method and for that i need to pass a valid uuid to r http.Request, please suggest how can i do that, I tried a few options from my test class like

```
req.URL.Query().Set("uuid", "valid_uuid")
```

But it did not work. How can I test this method by passing a valid uuid to request?

Comment: Never used `go-chi` as I always used `gorilla`. BTW, in this answer you should find the solution to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719412/14394371
If you're open to switch to `gorilla` I can provide you a complete example!

Comment: @IvanPesenti Please suggest that gorilla solution.

Comment: What does "But it did not work" mean? What error or other unexpected behavior did you see?

Answer (score 3):

Let me present my usual solution with `gorilla` package.

##### `handler.go` file

```golang
package httpunittest

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func GetProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    uuidString, isFound := params["uuid"]
    if !isFound {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte(uuidString))
}
```

Here, you use the function `Vars` to fetch all of the URL parameters present within the `http.Request`. Then, you've to look for the `uuid` key and do your business logic with it.

##### `handler_test.go` file

```golang
package httpunittest

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestGetProduct(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("WithUUID", func(t *testing.T) {
        r := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/products/1", nil) // note that this URL is useless
        r = mux.SetURLVars(r, map[string]string{"uuid": "1"})
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()

        GetProduct(w, r)

        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, w.Result().StatusCode)
    })

    t.Run("Without_UUID", func(t *testing.T) {
        r := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/products", nil) // note that this URL is useless
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()

        GetProduct(w, r)

        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusBadRequest, w.Result().StatusCode)
    })
}
```

First, I used the functions provided by the `httptest` package of the Go Standard Library that fits well for unit testing our HTTP handlers.
Then, I used the function `SetUrlVars` provided by the `gorilla` package that allows us to set the URL parameters of an `http.Request`.
Thanks to this you should be able to achieve what you need!

Comment: Hi @Anshul Sharma, did you manage it?